# How to solve an Invalid write/read of size 8 involving a void pointer in C

Tags: c, pointers, struct, while-loop, dynamic-memory-allocation

I am currently working on a hash table for a project and I am having some trouble with the memory cleanup. I am using Valgrind and I am getting this error response.

```
    ==1409499== Invalid write of size 8
    ==1409499==    at 0x4014F9: symtabInstall (symtab.c:106)
    ==1409499==    by 0x4011D0: main (test1.c:17)
    ==1409499==  Address 0x4a47128 is 0 bytes after a block of size 8 alloc'd
    ==1409499==    at 0x484086F: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:381)
    ==1409499==    by 0x4014B0: symtabInstall (symtab.c:102)
    ==1409499==    by 0x4011D0: main (test1.c:17)
    
    
    int symtabInstall(void *symtabHandle, const char *symbol, void *data){
        // Install a (symbol, data) pair in the table.
        // If the symbol is already installed in the table, then the data is
        //   overwritten.
        // If the symbol is not already installed, then space is allocated and
        //   a copy is made of the symbol, and the (symbol, data) pair is then
        //   installed in the table.
        // If successful, returns 1.
        // If memory cannot be allocated for a new symbol, then returns 0.
        // Note that no validation is made of the symbol table handle passed
        //   in. If not a valid handle, then the behavior is undefined (but
        //   probably bad).
        sym_t *symtable = symtabHandle;
        signed int location = search(symbol, symtable);
        if (location != -1)
            symtable->entries[location]->data = data;
        ///Create the input pair
        values *input = malloc(sizeof(input) * 1);
        if (input == NULL)
            return 0;
        input->symbol = malloc(strlen(symbol) + 1);
        input->data = data; /// This is the Line -------------------
        strcpy(input->symbol, symbol);
        ///Find spot to put in
        int symh = hash(symbol, symtable);
        ///Input check
        if (symtable->entries[symh] == NULL){
            symtable->entries[symh] = input;
        } else {
            int i = symh + 1;
            int c = 0;
            while(i < symtable->size){
                if (i == symtable->size && c == 0){
                    c = 1;
                } else if (c == 1){
                    return 0;
                }
                i %= symtable->size;
                if (symtable->entries[i] != NULL){
                    symtable->entries[symh] = input;
                    symtable->entries[symh]->data = data;
                }
                i++;
            }
        }
        return 1;
    }
```

For context, input is one of the buckets for the hash table and has two pointers symbol and data. Data is the one giving me the issue as I need to allocate memory for it.
Here are the structs for both.

```
    typedef struct values {
        char *symbol;
        void *data;
        struct values *next;
    } values;
    typedef struct{
        values **entries;
        int size;
    } sym_t;
```

I am also given no knowledge of the data type for data.

Comment: Please provide complete code as a [mre]. Specifically, we need to see how `input` was allocated/defined. As a new user please take the [tour] and read [ask] to understand the requirements of this site.

Comment: I'm sorry I forgot to put that in, is this good?

Comment: Not quite. Please read the link: [mre]. That means complete code that anyone can take exactly as shown to reproduce the number. And in this case we also need the exact code to correlate the line numbers in the valgrind output.

Comment: `malloc(sizeof(input) * 1)` needs to be `malloc(sizeof(*input))`. The main issue being that `sizeof(input)` is the size of a pointer and not the size of what it is pointing to as actually needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems the problem is this memory allocation

```
values *input = malloc(sizeof(input) * 1);
```

I think you mean

```
values *input = malloc(sizeof( *input) * 1);
```

or

```
values *input = malloc(sizeof(values) * 1);
```

Pay attention to that using the multi[plier `1` does not make a great sense.:)

Also you forgot to initialize the data member `next` of the allocated object of the type values.

And the body of this while loop

```
 while(i < symtable->size){
     if (i == symtable->size && c == 0){
     // ...
```

also does not make a great sense because the condition in the following if statement

```
i == symtable->size
```

never can evaluate to true.

Comment: Thanks for the help, and I will definitely use what you said here. Thanks.